# Unity 2D - How can I use a joystick to aim in a TopDown shooter game?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, touch, joystick

I have created a game in Unity 2D which is a 2D TopDown shooter game. I want to convert the game from PC to Android, so I need to create a joystick for aiming. Right now, I can aim where I want using my mouse with this code:

```
void FixedUpdate()
{

    rb.MovePosition(rb.position + movement * moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);

    Vector2 lookDir = mousePos - rb.position;
    float angle = Mathf.Atan2(lookDir.y, lookDir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    rb.rotation = angle;
}
```

How exactly can I create an on-screen joystick which reads the position of where I am dragging it, and use that position to point my character to the corresponding position?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You actually have a lot of the right concepts already in place from what I can see!

You understand what a vector is so that eliminates a lot of your work. Simply have an object on screen for your virtual joystick, with an anchor point that it always snaps back to.

When you click and drag your joystick (or drag it by touch) take the vector between the anchor and the dragged-to position of the joystick, and there's your aim angle!

Comment: Thank you! I managed to create a joystick for aiming and it works perfectly! The only problem is that I want to aim with one finger (for example on the left hand), and swipe up or down (up shoots something, and down shoots something different) with another finger from the other hand. The joystick appears whenever I touch the screen. When I hold down one finger to aim, and then swipe with the other, the joystick stays in the correct position (left hand for example), but it starts being aimed by the new finger placed (right hand). Any idea how to fix this? The game is in landscape mode. Thanks!

Comment: Hey, glad you're making progress!

Comment: Smeg, didn't mean for that comment to be so short. So, what you're looking for is information about multitouch. Here's a good post on the subject. Essentially, you need to treat the fingers seperately based on the order in which they touched the screen. Alternatively, you could put boundaries on the touch surface logic, so the joystick only appears if you touched on the left side of the screen and lives there, and the swipe controls are on the right of the screen! https://answers.unity.com/questions/1374162/how-to-implement-multi-touch-in-android-2d-game.html

Answer (score 0):

If your problem was *shoot when touch click ui*, use this code:

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0) && !(EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject()))
    print("Shoot");
```

And when your joystick for shoot add joystick handler from shoot direction in and the joystick direction rotate basis `Input.GetAxis`.
Anyway, comment if wrong answer.